# create a customized scrollable top Tab bar using react-navigation-tab?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-bottom-tab

i need to create a customized scrollable top tab bar using react navigation tabs and tabBarComponent without using any other third party library.

```
const TopTabBar = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    Home: HomePage,
    Entertainment: EntertainmentNews,
    Business: BusinessStack,
    Music: MusicStack,
    Politics: PoliticsStack,
    Sports: SportsStack,
    Technology: TechnologyStack,
    WorldNews: WorldNewsStack
}, {
    tabBarComponent: (props) => <TopTabBarComponent {...props}/>
})
```

In this with tab bar component i am able to create the top bar but it does not scroll when the screen are swiped ?

```
import React , { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList, TouchableOpacity, Animated, Dimensions} from 'react-native'

interface Props {
    navigation?: any
}

interface State {
    //
}

export class TopTabBarComponent extends Component <Props, State>{
    flatListRef
    constructor(props: Props, state: State){
        super(props, state)
    }





    onPressItem = (index) => {
        const { navigation } = this.props
        navigation.navigate( this.props.navigation.state.routes[index].routeName )
        // this.onScrollIndex(index)
    }

    renderTopBar = (item, index) => {
        const routes = this.props.navigation.state.routes
        const activeIndex = this.props.navigation.state.index

            return (
                <TouchableOpacity style = {{
                     alignItems: 'center' ,  
                     height: 50, 
                     justifyContent: 'center', 
                     borderBottomWidth: activeIndex === index ?  2 : 0, 
                     borderColor: 'green', 
                     paddingHorizontal: 5
                     }} onPress = {() => this.onPressItem(index)}>  
                    <Text style = {{ fontSize: 20, color: 'blue'}}>{item.routeName}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )
    }

    render() {
        // reactotron.log('this.props', this.props.navigation)
        console.warn('this.props.navigation.state.index', this.props.navigation.state.index)
        return(
            <View style = {{ marginHorizontal: 5}}>
                <FlatList
                    initialScrollIndex = { this.props.navigation.state.index }
                    ref = {(ref) => { this.flatListRef = ref}}
                    // style = {{ paddingHorizontal: 20}}
                    horizontal
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = {false}
                    data = {this.props.navigation.state.routes}
                    renderItem = {({item , index}) => this.renderTopBar(item, index) }
                    ItemSeparatorComponent = {() => <View style = {{ paddingRight: 40}}/>}
                    />
            </View>
        )
    }

}
```

This is top tab bar component code ? So how can i make the top tab scroll automatically when the screens are swiped ?

Answer (score 5):

This is a sample to my tab bar that I quickly edited for your test case.

```
function MyTabBar({ state, descriptors, navigation, position }) {
    const scrollViewRef = useRef(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({ x: state.index * 50, y: 0, animated: true })
    }, [state.index])

    return (
        <View style={styles.tabContainer}>
            <ScrollView ref={list => scrollViewRef.current = list} contentContainerStyle={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}} horizontal>
                {state.routes.map((route, index) => {
                    const { options } = descriptors[route.key];
                    const label =
                        options.tabBarLabel !== undefined
                        ? options.tabBarLabel
                        : options.title !== undefined
                        ? options.title
                        : route.name;

                    const isFocused = state.index === index;
                    const onPress = () => {
                        const event = navigation.emit({
                        type: 'tabPress',
                        target: route.key,
                        });

                        if (!isFocused && !event.defaultPrevented) {
                        navigation.navigate(route.name);
                        }
                    };

                    const onLongPress = () => {
                        navigation.emit({
                        type: 'tabLongPress',
                        target: route.key,
                        });
                    };

                    let focusStyle = { }; //style object to append to the focussed tab
                    let tintColor = { };
                    let fontColor = { };
                    isFocused ? focusStyle = { backgroundColor: 'darkgray' } : focusStyle = { };
                    isFocused ? tintColor = { tintColor: 'black' } : tintColor = { tintColor: 'lightgray' }; // TODO: change this with proper fontColor codes
                    isFocused ? fontColor = { color: 'black' } : fontColor = { color: 'lightgray' };
                    //below controls the rendered tab

                        return (
                            <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                                key={index}
                                onPress={onPress}
                                onLongPress={onLongPress}
                                style={[styles.tabItem, focusStyle]}
                            >
                                    <View style={styles.tabIconContainer}>
                                        <LearnTabIcon title={route.name} color={tintColor} />
                                    </View>
                                    <Text style={[styles.labelStyle, fontColor]}>
                                        {label}
                                    </Text>
                            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                        );
                })}
            </ScrollView>

            <View style={styles.tabBarIndicator}>
                { state.routes.map((route, index) => {
                    const isFocused = state.index === index;
                    let selectedStyle = { };
                    isFocused ? selectedStyle = { backgroundColor: 'darkgray'} : { }; // TODO: change this coloring to actual color codes
                    return (
                        <View 
                            style={[styles.tabIndicators, selectedStyle]}
                            key={index}
                        >
                        </View>
                    );
                })}
            </View>
        </View>
    );
  }
```

I'm using functional components for everything so it will look a bit different but in your custom tab bar grab the `state.index` on each index change and then use `scrollToOffset` to control where the scroll view is centered on screen.  I put in a sample 50px offset scale just for simplicity.

I also wasn't using TypeScript but you seem to have most the boiler plate already ready to go anyway.

Comment: what is the use of using the last view that is after the scrollview

Comment: Oh sorry that was just part of my TabBar component to show a state indicator track.  You don't need that @rohitgarg

Comment: Is there is any way to animate this scrollable tab bar when the screen are being swiped ? If you know any way please help me .

Comment: `scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({ x: state.index * 50, y: 0, animated: true })` by using `animated: true` it will animate by default to the offset specified

Comment: I want to show the animation when i am swiping the screen . Like if a swipe a little bit of the screen i want my tab bar to move according to that swipe

Comment: Is there is any event that triggers on swiping in createMaterialTopTabNavigator

Comment: I used a materialTopTabNavigator with the above custom Tab navigator component and it has the ability to be swipeable by default.

Comment: My tab bar also scrolls . But it scrolls after the page is completely swiped to another screen . I want to show the animation along the swiping . If i swipe 10% of the screen i want my top tab bar to scroll 10 %.

Comment: You'd have to set up some a custom animation.  I would look into `Animated` library from `react-native` and /or `react-native-reanimated`

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react'
import {StatusBar} from 'react-native'

import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native'

import {GestureHandlerRootView} from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import {createMaterialTopTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs'
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen'
import LivingRoom from './screens/LivingRoom'
import Fav from './screens/Fav'
import Settings from './screens/Settings'

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator()

const AppRoot = () => {
  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView className="flex-1">
      <StatusBar hidden />
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator
          screenOptions={{
            tabBarScrollEnabled: true,
            tabBarIndicator: () => null,
            tabBarStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#000',
            },
            tabBarItemStyle: {
              width: 'auto',
              alignItems: 'flex-start',
            },
            tabBarLabelStyle: {
              fontSize: 30,
              fontFamily: 'Satoshi-Black',
              color: '#fff',
              textTransform: 'capitalize',
            },
          }}
          sceneContainerStyle={{backgroundColor: '#000'}}>
          <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Living Room" component={LivingRoom} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Fav" component={Fav} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  )
}

export default AppRoot
```

[image]